# PHP : connecting to a Firebird (Interbase) database with Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, firebird, zend-db, interbase

I'm trying to connect to a Firebird database using the Zend Framework library (see Zend docs here : http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.adapter.html)

The `php_interbase.dll` extension is activated. If I run this code:

```
$db = Zend_Db::factory('Php_Interbase', array(
    "host"      =>  "127.0.0.1",
    "username"  =>  "xxxxxx",
    "password"  =>  "xxxxxx",
    "dbname"    =>  "xxxxxx"
));
```

I get this error message:

**Warning: include_once(Zend\Db\Adapter\Php\Interbase.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\php\includes\Zend\Loader.php on line 146**

Indeed `Interbase.php` file seems to be absent from the library (while all other DB drivers mentioned in the docs are present). What should I do? Where can I download the missing file(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This adapter was released in version 1.7.3 in "extras" library, in the "Full Package". as per the last comment here
http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFPROP/Zend_Db%2BFirebird-Interbase%2Bsupport

Comment: Thanks. I now see that the adapter is present in the `extras` folder in the version I've just downloaded (1.11.11). Does it mean I just have to move the files to the `library` directory?
Do you know how reliable is this adapter?

Comment: OR you could tell the zend loader to look into that folder.

Comment: Since its prefix is ZendX, I suggest you to place in library folder and autoload should automatically work.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be working. I copied the ZendX folder in the library folder, and added `"adapterNamespace" =>   "ZendX_Db_Adapter"` in the factory's second parameter.